# Wordpress - create multilingual plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, translation, multilingual

I have some problems creating a multilingual plugin.

Overview:

```
MyPluginFolder
  my-plugin.php
  languages
    my-plugin-de_DE.po
    my-plugin-de_DE.mo
```

my-plugin.php :

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_init');

function my_plugin_init() {
  load_plugin_textdomain('my-plugin', 
  dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages');
}
```

It doesn't display my translation.

- Checked the domain for __(); & _e(); functions
- read that there is a possibility that the translation file is read to early

I don't know what I do wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

the parameter **false** in the load_plugin_textdomain is important!

```
 load_plugin_textdomain('fcg-manager', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/languages/');
```

Comment: I was about to answer but you got it first. Make sure you read the documentation more carefully next time, it'll save you a lot of headaches in the future :)

Comment: Yes ofcourse but in the documentation there is this sentence where i thought i dont have to use this parameter: $abs_rel_path (Deprecated)
(string) (optional) Relative path to ABSPATH of a folder, where the .mo file resides. **Deprecated, but still functional until 2.7**
Default: false  --- Thank you for your effort!

Comment: I understand where your confusion comes from. That basically means "this parameter was being used for something prior to WP 2.7, after that we no longer needed it anymore but couldn't remove it from the function definition without breaking other people's code." Which means you still need to define it, even if WordPress won't use it.